# Ordering a array of arrays in a 'fair' manner

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I have an array of arrays created with N=9

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b = a.combination(2).to_a
```

I would like to take `N%2` of the sub-arrays out at a time with no number occurring twice, for example the first time this would be:

```
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]
```

This means 9 was not picked. A second time I would take out

```
[[1,3],[2,4],[5,7],[6,8]]
```

Again 9 not being picked.
Eventually I would be left with

```
 [[1,9],[2,9],[3,9],[4,9],[5,9],[6, 9],[7, 9],[8, 9]]
```

which means I can no longer pick 4 arrays with no duplicate numbers.

How can I order my array so that each number is left out only once instead of 9 all the time?

The use case is as follows:

```
students = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
available_combinations = a.combination(2).to_a

def make_pairs
 available_students = students
 while available_students.length > 1 do
  student_combination = find_sub_array(available_combinations, available_students.first, available_students)
   available_combinations.delete(student_combination)
   available_students -= student_combination
 end
end

 def find_sub_array(available_combinations, student, available_students)
 available_combinations.each do |subarray|
  if subarray.include?(student) && (subarray - available_students).empty?
    return subarray
  end
 end
end
```

I would like to run make_pairs multiple times, until available_combinations no longer has enough pairs left.

Comment: What does "fair" mean? Can you give an example of a "fair ordering"? Is it fair to say that your requirements are specific to **this array**? Because I don't know what behaviour you would expect to see **in general**.

Comment: For example... If your (unusual) requirement is actually "I want to get 4 arrays of pairs of elements, with no duplicates" then you could do: `a.uniq.sample(8).each_slice(2).to_a`

Comment: I've added some more information to my question, hopefully it is more clear like this.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you've written so far.

Comment: So you want this method to be non-deterministic? You will get different results each time, and sometimes even a different *number* of results.

Comment: Hold on, I'll add more of the code so it is hopefully more clear what I am trying to do.

Comment: You could add a hash to count the number of times a student has already been picked. Then, instead of always starting with the first available student, you start with the one (ones) that was (were) picked least often.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. Your code is incomplete, and you've only given an example of what a "fair order" *isn't*, rather than what it *is*. Could you not just randomise the result? (Although that's really not what I'd call an "ordering".)

Comment: Is this a good analogy? 9 chessplayers, each play all others once, nine rounds in total, every player having a no game round once.

Comment: @steenslag Yes, that's right.

Comment: @Xizam Then that is called a "round-robin" tournament. Wikipedia gives some algorithms.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For odd numbers, just add another dummy number like `0` or `:bye`:

```
students = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,:bye]
```

Now when you pull n%2 pairs, at least one will be paired with a :bye. That is the odd student out in that pairing. Each student will have an equal number of :bye rounds.

Edit: I'm assuming you are pulling 5 pairs in this example and discarding the pair with the :bye to ensure it doesn't repeat.

Comment: This does not work with the current system. With 9 students and 1 bye the algorithm will get stuck in the second iteration, where student 9 and the bye will be the only ones left for the second time in a row.

Comment: In this example you have to pull 5 pairs and discard the pair with the :bye to make it work.